# WPF TabControl/TabItem Active, Deactive and Closing

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I am trying to capture when a tab becomes active, deactive and closing.  The TabControl doesn't seem to have any events that I can trap for these scenerios.

Our system requires a user to click "Save" when a user leaves a tab and goes to another part of the program. (If they have made changes to the data on that tab).

Any thoughts or suggestions? or Any other controls that I could use instead that does have this functionality?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try the **SelectionChanged** event of the TabControl. This will give you the **SelectedItem** and **SelectedIndex** properties of the current tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your custom class that derives from `TabItem`, let's say

```
public class MyTabItem : TabItem 
{
       protected override void OnSelected(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSelected(e);

        }


        protected override void OnUnselected(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnUnselected(e);

        }
}
```

Inside you can handle selection and unselection of the tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MVVM pattern with a ViewModel, with a collection of viewmodels as your tab items, you could keep a reference to a ICollectionView in the ViewModel, like this:

```
public ICollectionView MyTabItemsCollectionView{ get; set; }
```

Then in the constructor, set it and create event handlers for the CurrentChanging event

```
MyTabItemsCollectionView= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyTabItemsCollection);
MyTabItemsCollectionView.CurrentChanging += MyTabItemsCollectionViewCurrentChanging;
```

Then, in the event handler, do whatever you need to prevent the user from closing it

```
void WorkspacesCollectionViewCurrentChanging(object sender, CurrentChangingEventArgs e)
{
    if (UserShouldNotBeAllowedToDoThis())
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```